# getting force close while running the android application

Tags: android

While running my application  i am getting the below given warning and application went force close.

```
[2011-10-17 12:09:09 - LunarLander] WARNING: Application does not specify an API level requirement!
[2011-10-17 12:09:09 - LunarLander] Device API version is 9 (Android 2.3.1)
```

How to resolve this. I created another emulator with API level 10, then also i am getting the same error.

Comment: update your manifest file here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am sure you forget to define the API level inside the AndroidManifest.xml file, define it as:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="5"
             android:maxSdkVersion="10"
             android:targetSdkVersion="8"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should define the API level of your application in manifest file. I think you forgot to that. Launch the application according to that.

Answer (score 1):

Just looking at that error you need to specify an API level for your application:

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html